# Query firebase collection in collection can't get documents

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all my documents (if they are based on query) using firebase.
So my firebase structure is :

[image]

I tried my method and I use empthy to check if there are documents , but i always get TRUE , but i think the path is incorect because i have 2 documents inside "ListaFavorite".

```
 firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`users`)
      .doc(`${this.MyUser.uid}`)
      .collection("ListaFavorite")
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        const check = result.empty;
        console.log("DATA is: " + check);
      });
```

So based on the query i want to get all the documents from there and show in my html page. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListaFavorite` is a field, not a subcollection. This means you will have to address it as a field, instead of trying to load it as a subcollection.

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(`users`)
  .doc(`${this.MyUser.uid}`)
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    const check = doc.data().ListaFavorite;
    console.log("DATA is: " + check);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you sir , it works now. My bad i didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListaFavorite` is a field of `${this.MyUser.uid}` document and *not* a subcollection. Depending on your usage, you can either change it so it is a subcollection via the `+ Start collection` button, or you can check it with:

```js
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(`${this.MyUser.uid}`)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const check = doc.get('ListaFavorite');
        console.log("DATA is: " + check);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you ! Didn't know that. I've modified and it works.